Make separate file output and behaivour depending on the logging level in python?
I'm trying to do something which seems a bit unorthodox but makes sense for me in a project I'm working on. I have seen a lot of questions that are asking similar or parts of my question but couldn't find a method that works as I'd like. Maybe it's impossible to do without creating a whole library out of it, I think I might be trying to find a simple solution to a complicated task.
The idea is that I'd like to change the logging level when running the script for example: debug, info, warning and so on.
But I'd like to have separate output files for each level, so debug.txt, info.txt, warning.txt. I would also like to have each one going to different outputs. For example, I'd like the debug and info  to be sent to both file and console, while the warning to only go to console.
I've found complicated methods that do this, but for example will always create a file for debug even if there are no debug messages sent, even if the whole script was set to only warning.
My application is a script that does a bunch of things and that's it. The idea is that when given to a user, I'd like them to see warnings and errors printed to a file since they don't really look at or care for a console with the exe file I send them. But then when I'm troubleshooting, I'd like to turn on debug mode and see the console output and the a debug specific log.
I tried creating different loggers and handlers, but it gets complicated. Sometimes I would get outputs in the wrong files or things don't behave as expected. I have code snippets of trials, I can clean them and post them, but I think I'm better off starting with a clean slate. The other issue is creating a file handler forces creating a new file even if it's not being used, which I don't want that. I would like to only produce a log file if there's a problem, to not confuse the user.

Show us an actual code example that doesn't do what you expected.

Were you trying to use a single handler, or did you fail at trying to add multiple, level-specific handlers to a single logger?

Do you want a logged message to go only to a specific file, for example, debug(...) only writes to debug.txt, not warning.txt, error.txt, etc, as well?

Creating a file handler with keyword argument delay=True only creates/opens the file if it's going to be written to.

You can use a wrapper on every function using a class to store all of the different log-level messages. This requires a logging initializer based on the level, another function to parse messages into log files. used on the return of each function.
    class ErrorMessaging():
         def __init__(self, log_level):
              self.log_level = log_level
              self.debug_message = ''
              self.info_message = ''
              self.warning_message = ''
              self.error_message = ''
              self.critical_message = ''
              self.level_order = ['Critical', 'Error', 'Warning', 'Info', 'Debug']
         # Seperate all messages based on Category like asked by chepner 
         def log_messages(self):
              message_lookup = {'Critical':self.critical_message,
                                'Error':self.error_message,
                                'Warning':self.warning_message,
                                'Info':self.info_message,
                                'Debug':self.debug_message}
              for level in self.level_order:
                   log = logging.getLogger(level)
                   log_message_lookup ={'Critical':log.critical,
                                        'Error':log.error,
                                        'Warning':log.warning,
                                        'Info':log.info,
                                        'Debug':log.debug}
                   for msg in message_lookup[level].split('\n'):
                       log_message_lookup[level](msg)
                   # Do not log lower log levels then set level
                   if level == self.log_level:
                       break
             # Reset all Log string storage to empty
             for level in self.level_order:
                 message_lookup[level] = ''

         def alternative_log_message(self, msg, level):
             """All messages have level and record down the line and get 
                 more information the lower level you go e.g. Error in Debug
             requires calling method with level and logging internally in functions,
           could avoid using wrapper and logging after function completes. 
Finally would want to alter stdout stream handler to only activate once 
other version would only log and console write for that level."""
             message = f"[{level. Upper()}] - {msg}"
             for level in self.level_order:
                   log = logging.getLogger(level)
                   # Would require transferring lookups from main method
                   log_message_lookup[level](msg)
                   if level == self.log_level:
                       break

         def initialize_logs(self, output_folder):
              file_format = logging. Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
              for level in self.level_order:
                   log = logging.getLogger(level)
                   file_handler = logging.FileHandler(f"{output_folder}\\{level}.log")
                   file_handler.setFormatter(file_format)
                   log.addHandler(file_handler)
                   if level in ['Debug', 'Info', 'Warning']:
                       handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
                       handler.setFormatter(file_format)
                       log.addHandler(handler)
                   if level == self.log_level:
                       break

from functools import wraps
log_object_instance = ErrorMessaging('Warning')
log_object_instance.initialize_logs(<some_directory>)

def log(log_object_instance):
    def log_wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def log_functionality(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal log_object_instance
            fail_exit = False
            try:
                # Wrap Every function and include log_msg in every signature
                response = fn(*args, log_msg = log_object_instance, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                # Could add traceback ect..
                critical_msg = f"{func.__name__} Failed: {e}"
                log_object_instance.critical += critical_msg
                fail_exit = True
            log_object_instance.log_messages()

            if fail_exit:
                #sys.stderr.write(critical_msg) Users do not want console for critical message
                sys.exit(1)
            return response
        return log_functionality
    return log_wrapper

In functions example -> log_msg.debug += "Debug message\n"
all message level must end in new line.

If I understood correctly you want a logging system for different levels. You could use the logging module which is from pythons' standard library.
Make a class to encapsulates the logging setup. You can customize the log file name and the levels for console and file logging.
import logging

class SimpleLogger:
    def __init__(self, log_file="app.log", console_level=logging.INFO, file_level=logging.DEBUG):

        self.logger = logging.getLogger("SimpleLogger")
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setLevel(console_level)

        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
        file_handler.setLevel(file_level)

        self.logger.addHandler(console_handler)
        self.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    def debug(self, message):
        self.logger.debug(message)

    def info(self, message):
        self.logger.info(message)

    def warning(self, message):
        self.logger.warning(message)

    def error(self, message):
        self.logger.error(message)

    def critical(self, message):
        self.logger.critical(message)

logger = SimpleLogger()

message = "string"
logger.debug(f"{message} (file only)")
logger.warning(f"{message} (console and file)")

Just simply create a SimpleLogger instance using different parameters.
error_logger = SimpleLogger("error.txt", console_level=logging.ERROR, file_level=logging.ERROR )


There's no real reason to make this a class, at least not unless you plan on separate instances creating different loggers by passing a different name to getLogger.

Well it does help to keep your code clean and organized, different instances can be bundle and reused. It makes code cleaner in general and reduces redundancy.

Not in this specific case. 90% of your code is boilerplate duplication of Logger methods, and as I pointed out, your multiple instances would all just trample on the same underlying Logger instance.

This is an example I gave to briefly demonstrate  the basics of what the logging module offers.

It's a bad example. The logging module is specifically designed so that you don't need to wrap Logger instances in another class. getLogger doesn't necessarily create a new instance; it returns an existing instance with the given name.

Please go ahead and answer the post yourself in this case. I'd really appreciate it if you could show me a better way of doing this.

I'm still waiting for the OP to provide a clearer statement of what they want to actually happen.
